# Can I have MySQL multiple slave-master per schema on one instance?

Tags: mysql, replication

Simple issue, some data is processed on different servers, while other on different servers.

Can I have on one instance on MySQL:
-SchemaA master on server A - slave on server B
-SchemaB slave on server A - master server B

My queries are joining data between schemas so I would like to juml out of galera cluster to mix of master-slave approach on schema basis

Comment: whats with Master / Master replication. So you can manage the read write permissions with the login

Comment: Master / master is too limiting in terms of writes, besides there is many schemas/apps in different locations, so I want to create master/slave and slave/master in same instance per schema basis